# 'If' inside the 'For' crashes the game - C language

Tags: c

Here is a code: (whyerror1.exe)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int i, n, health=100;
int main(void)
{
    for (i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        printf("health: %d\n",health);
        printf("There is meat on the ground.\n");
        printf("Will you eat it?\n");
        printf("1: yes  2: no\n"); 
        scanf("%d", n);
        if(n==1) {
                      system("cls");
                      printf("Ate it. \n");
                      printf("There is no people, so it is safe to eat. \n");
                      printf("Health is increased.\n");
                      system("pause>nul");
                      system("cls");
                      }
        else if(n==2) {
                      system("cls");
                      printf("Didn't ate it. \n");
                      printf("More hunger, less health. \n");
                      system("pause>nul");
                      system("cls");
                      }
        else {
                     printf("select between 1 and 2. \n");
                     system("pause>nul");
                     system("cls");
                     i=-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Result: whyerror1.exe stopped working.
Why is this happening?
I already tried selecting other numbers. I tried any numbers!
Plz help!

Comment: cfr xorguy's answer here under. As a side note, you should never manipulate the index of a for loop inside the loop. Actually this is the typical case where you shouldn't use a for loop at all, but `while  ` or `do...while`

Comment: @Bartdude Oh, I didn't know that. Well, it actually worked, but using while will be better. Thanks for telling me that.

Comment: @Bartdude in this (and many) cases, I agree that one shouldn't manipulate the `for` index within the loop, however to say _you should never_, in this case, is too overreaching. A recent example I had which I consider quite legitimate was `for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)` to parse command line arguments. Some arguments require a parameter, others don't, and I advanced i within the loop to bypass parameters I consumed before `for` would have reached them.

Comment: @user3022392 > yes it worked, but it's bad practice. As a basic "rule", remember you should only use `for` loops for a known and limited (limited in the sense of "countable", not "few") number of iterations. FYI , and if I'm not mistaken,some more advanced languages simply refuse to compile if you attempt to modify this index variable...

Comment: @mah > Well, it works as the example here above works, but I still think the `for` loop should not be used that way. You could have achieved the same with a while loop, incrementing the index as you wish inside it. Now maybe I'm too picky on this, but I've always considered it "bad design" (as I consider the use of `break` inside loops a bad design, even if it works...)

Comment: @Bartdude so you're ok with increasing the variable inside `while` but not inside `for`? Though I don't agree, I can see your point (since `for` is more formal in its definition and manipulation, and `while` often requires inside manipulation).

Comment: @mah > actually when I need to loop on a collection and can't use a `foreach` (depends on the language/collection), I always put at least 2 conditions for the `while` : 1 is for the "index" not to go over boundaries, the other would be testing a simple boolean flag to force the exit. That way, when you're exiting the loop, you can also identify if you exited at the end of its iterations, or because of a "forced" exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", n);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```